# Binomial expansion of square root

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion, approximation

I want to find the value of the square root 
$$(a+ b x^2 + c x)^{0.5}$$
by knowing that $x$ is very small ($x$ goes to zero).

Could anyone help me to decide what to do? How can I do that? Is the binomial expansion a good method to find the approximate value of the square root to second order in $x$? If yes, how should I binomial expand it?
$a$ could be a negative number or an imaginary number or a positive number.

Comment: What do you mean by $x$ is small?

Comment: goes to zero @MANMAID

Comment: That's okk, but that does not specify how much you need. You need to say approx. up to $x^2$ or $x^3$ etc.

Comment: small is small...

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that for $|z|<1$,
$$(1+z)^{1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{1/2}{n}z^n=1+\frac{z}{2}-\frac{z^2}{8}+o(z^2).$$
Now for $a\not=0$, the second order expansion at $0$ is
$$(a+ b x^2 + c x)^{1/2}=r(1+z)^{1/2}=r\left(1+\frac{cx}{2a}+\frac{(4ab-c^2)x^2}{8a^2}+o(x^2)\right)$$
where $z=(b x^2 + c x)/a$ and $r$ is the [principal square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Principal_square_root_of_a_complex_number) of $a$ (or $r=\sqrt{a}$ if we are dealing with real numbers and $a>0$).

Comment: Why should a be positive? It could also be negative. a could also be imaginary number

Comment: could you complete your answer by adding the conditions in which "a" is negative and another condition in which a is an imaginry number

Comment: If complex number are involved then are you consedering the principal squareroot? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Principal_square_root_of_a_complex_number

Comment: But I need the solution to the second order in x

Comment: @OLIVER range See my edited answer.

Comment: Is the solution correct in the situation in which a, x and b are real numbers but c is completely imaginary?

Comment: @OLIVER range I think it is correct, Why are you asking this? It would be nice to have a feedback. BTW, if are new here https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I'm thinking if the solution is correct or not

Comment: @OLIVER range What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Put $bx^2+cx=at $ with $a>0$.

$$(a+bx^2+cx)^{1/2}=a^{1/2}(1+t)^{1/2} $$

$(1+t)^{1/2}=1+\frac {t}{2}+\frac {1/2 (1/2-1)}{2!}t^2+
... +\frac {1/2 (1/2-1)... (1/2-n+1)}{n!}t^n+... $

Comment: Why should a be positive? It could also be negative. "a" could also be an imaginary number